# More complex alternatives for 'A mon avis' in a formal tone

Tags: expressions, phrase

What are other phrases in French to express your opinion eg. 'À mon avis', in a complex and sophisticated manner.

Comment: An opinion is an opinion on a subject. I do not understand what you mean by "in a complex and sophisticated manner". Do you mean something like a **thorough explanation**? Are you referring to the type of explanation a person gives?

Answer (score 1):

*SIMPLE ÉQUIVALENCE*

- **être d'avis que**  (indicatif) (*langue familière, TLFi*)
  *Il est d'avis que les envahisseurs vont passer par les montagnes.*
- **mon/son/leur/notre opinion est que**
  *Leur opinion est qu'il faut attendre des jours plus chauds.*

*IDÉE AJOUTÉES*

*expression d'un souhait, TLFi*

- **être d'avis que (subjonctif)**
  *Je suis d'avis que nous n'allions pas à la foire aujourd'hui, il pourrait y avoir une échauffourée.*
- **être d'avis de (infinitif)**
  *C'est parce qu'il était d'avis de travailler tard que nous sommes encore là.*

*L'avis est fondé sur un raisonnement, une conception, une façon de voir*

- **selon ma/ta/sa/leur compréhension (de, du, de la)**
  *Une telle possibilité n'existe pas, selon sa compréhension.*
- **tel(le)(s) que je/tu le (la) (les) conçoit**
  *Les vacances, telles qu'elle les conçoit, ne sont des vacances que si elle a à sa disposition assez de personnel pour ne jamais devoir allumer sa cigarette elle-même.*
- **à mon/son/leur point de vue**   (*langue familière, TLFi*)
  *À son point de vue vous n'y arriverez pas.*
- **selon mon/son/leur optique** (personnelle)
  *Selon son optique les cables sont disposés de façon plus sûre en cas d'incendie.*

*Locutions plus fortes qui, selon le  Wiktionnaire, « amoindrissent l’affirmation qui leur est associée et la rendent plus douteuse », lui conférant ainsi un peu la nature d'une opinion, d'un avis*

- **autant que je sache**
  *Autant que je sache, il y a dans cette maison  des traces qui portent à croire qu'elle était encore habité récemment.*
- **à ma connaissance**
  — *À ma connaissance il n'y a plus de trains après dix heures du soir.*
  On pourra reprendre ces paroles par exemple avec la phrase suivante.
  *À son avis il n'y aurait pas de train après dix heures.*
- **que je sache**
  *Tu ne comptes pas faire du ski en short que je sache, alors laisse ta collection de shorts à la maison.*
- **pour autant que je sache**
  *Pour autant que je sache, il faut que jeunesse se passe.*

Note : Il me semble qu'il soit possible de trouver encore plus de possibilités ; ne pas penser que les locutions qui ont été collectées ci-dessus seraient toutes celles qui existent.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:
Simple:

> D'après moi...
> À mon humble avis...

More complex:.

> Selon ma compréhension...
> Selon ma propre compréhension...